# Vowpal Wabbit LDA : Model Selection

Tags: python, vowpalwabbit

Is there any way within VW to compare model fits for LDA? Is the progressive loss output by the software at all meaningful for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

When running `vw -h --lda 1` the help offers the following parameters.
The `metrics` parameter is off by default.
It is used to compute the topic coherence which is implemented [here](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/4eeecd343392923928fb0e256df01bd601062edb/vowpalwabbit/lda_core.cc#L1280-L1293).
Try to enable this functionality by passing `--metrics 1`

```
Latent Dirichlet Allocation:
  --lda arg                             Run lda with <int> topics

  --lda_alpha arg (=0.100000001)        Prior on sparsity of per-document topic
                                        weights
  --lda_rho arg (=0.100000001)          Prior on sparsity of topic 
                                        distributions
  --lda_D arg (=10000)                  Number of documents
  --lda_epsilon arg (=0.00100000005)    Loop convergence threshold
  --minibatch arg (=1)                  Minibatch size, for LDA
  --math-mode arg (=0)                  Math mode: simd, accuracy, fast-approx
  --metrics arg (=0)                    Compute metrics
```

Or directly jump into the [source code of vw utility](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/4eeecd343392923928fb0e256df01bd601062edb/utl/vw-lda#L350-L391).

A helpful presentation showcasing most parameters can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/lda.pdf).

### Python: In case you were using gensim

(You tagged this question with `python`)

If you were using the python wrapper which was offered in [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim_3.8.3/models/wrappers/ldavowpalwabbit.html) (< 4.0.0), you can simply use Gensim as if you would have trained the model by Gensim itself after using `vwmodel2ldamodel` or directly use `log_perplexity` or other [coherence measures](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/coherencemodel.html).

A good tutorial on how to compare multiple LDA models can be found [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/howtos/run_compare_lda.html).

Answer (score -1):

In R statistical package you could diagnose model's fit with such procedure

[How to compute the log-likelihood of the LDA model in vowpal wabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31561067/how-to-compute-the-log-likelihood-of-the-lda-model-in-vowpal-wabbit)

I also asks there about that opportunity in VW