# How to compute the log-likelihood of the LDA model in vowpal wabbit

Tags: r, lda, vowpalwabbit

I am typical, regular, everyday R user. In R there is very helpful `lda.collapsed.gibbs.sampler` in [`lda`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lda/lda.pdf) package tha uses a collapsed Gibbs sampler to fit a latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA) model and returns point estimates of the latent parameters using the state at the last iteration of Gibbs sampling.

This function also has a great parameter `compute.log.likelihood` which, when set to `TRUE`, will cause the sampler to compute the log
likelihood of the words (to within a constant factor) after each sweep over the
variables. **This is useful for assessing convergence and in comparing different LDA models (computeted for different number of topics).**

I am interested if there is such an option in [vowpal_wabbit's LDA](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Latent-Dirichlet-Allocation) model?

Answer (score 0):

When running `vw -h --lda 1` the help offers the following parameters.
The `metrics` parameter is off by default.
It is used to compute the topic coherence which is implemented [here](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/4eeecd343392923928fb0e256df01bd601062edb/vowpalwabbit/lda_core.cc#L1280-L1293).
Try to enable this functionality by passing `--metrics 1`

```
Latent Dirichlet Allocation:
  --lda arg                             Run lda with <int> topics

  --lda_alpha arg (=0.100000001)        Prior on sparsity of per-document topic
                                        weights
  --lda_rho arg (=0.100000001)          Prior on sparsity of topic 
                                        distributions
  --lda_D arg (=10000)                  Number of documents
  --lda_epsilon arg (=0.00100000005)    Loop convergence threshold
  --minibatch arg (=1)                  Minibatch size, for LDA
  --math-mode arg (=0)                  Math mode: simd, accuracy, fast-approx
  --metrics arg (=0)                    Compute metrics
```

Or directly jump into the [source code of vw utility](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/4eeecd343392923928fb0e256df01bd601062edb/utl/vw-lda#L350-L391).

A helpful presentation showcasing most parameters can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/lda.pdf).